# What is the purpose of gasLimit in an EIP1559 transaction?

Tags: transactions, gas, gas-limit, eip-1559

When rlp encoding an EIP1559 transaction 3 gas values are provided: `maxPriorityFeePerGas`,`maxFeePerGas` & `gasLimit`.

`maxFeePerGas` = `BaseFee` + `maxPriorityFeePerGas` but what is the purpose of `gasLimit` and how does it interact with the other 2 gas properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The purpose of gas limit is to specify the maximum amount of gas you are willing to consume in a transaction. EIP-1559 introduces a `maxFeePerGas` and `maxPriorityFeePerGas`. These values determine how much you are willing to pay per gas used by the transaction. Similarly to how the gas price works, if your transaction has a `maxPriorityFeePerGas` of 10 Gwei and your transaction uses 21,000 gas (`gasLimit`), you will end up paying (at most) 21,000 × 10 Gwei = 0.00021 Ether.

How much you actually pay depends on the `BaseFee`, however. With a max fee of 10 Gwei and a `BaseFee` of 5 Gwei, you will end up paying only 5 Gwei per gas (ignoring the priority fee for now). The `maxFeePerGas` specifies how much you are willing to pay at most. If this number is lower than the current `BaseFee`, your transaction won't be confirmed (until the `BaseFee` drops or the transaction is removed from the transaction pool).

Comment: thanks @Yongjian that makes sense so every opcode in a contract ex. `PUSH1` gas: 3 is multiplied by (`baseFee` + `maxPriority`) or `maxFee` .  So when interacting with a contract, the contract needs to be completely simulated first to figure out the gas units consumed to populate `gasLimit`?